# Scrapy - Visiting nested links and grabbing meta data from each level

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am relatively new to scrapy and have been getting a lot of exceptions...
Here is what I am trying to do:

There 4 nested links that I want to grab data from:
Let's say I have 5 items that I want to crawl in total. These items are

```
Industry=scrapy.Field()
Company=scrapy.Field()
Contact_First_name=scrapy.Field()
Contact_Last_name=scrapy.Field()
Website=scrapy.Field()
```

1. Now to begin crawling I would first have to get the Industry.
   The Industry xpath also contains the link to individual listings of companies that belong to their Industry segments.
2. Next I want to use the Industry xpath and go into the link. This page does not contain any data that I want to crawl. But this page contains href links to individual companies that have their own basic info page.
3. Using the href link from the listings page, I now arrive at one page that contains the information for one company. Now I want to scrape the Company, Address, and Website.
   There is another href link that I need to click in order to lead to Contact_First_Name, Contact_Last_Name.
4. Using the href link, I now arrive at another page that contains the Contact_First_Name, and Contact_Last_Name

   `After crawling all of these pages, I should have items that look somewhat like this: 
   Industry    Company    Website    Contact_First_Name     Contact_Last_Name
   Finance      JPMC       JP.com       Jamie                 Dimon
   Finance      BOA        BOA.com      Bryan                 Moynihan
   Technology   ADSK       ADSK.com     Carl                  Bass`

EDITED

Here is the code that is working. Anzel's recommendations really helped out but i realized the subclass allowed_domains was wrong which stopped the nested links from following through. Once I changed it, it works.

```
class PschamberSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="pschamber"
    allowed_domains = ["cm.pschamber.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://cm.pschamber.com/list/"]


    def parse(self, response):
        item = PschamberItem()
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="mn-ql"]/ul/li/a'):
            # xpath and xpath().extract() will return a list
            # extract()[0] will return the first element in the list
            item['Industry'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            # another mistake you made here
            # you're trying to call scrapy.Request(LIST of hrefs) which will fail
            # scrapy.Request only takes a url string, not list
            # another big mistake is you're trying to yield the item,
            # whereas you should yield the Request object
            yield scrapy.Request(sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0], callback=self.parse_2, meta={'item': item})

    # another mistake, your callback function DOESNT take item as argument
    def parse_2(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('.//*[@id="mn-members"]/div/div/div/div/div/a').extract():
            # you can access your response meta like this
            item=response.meta['item']
            item['Company'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0], callback=self.parse_3, meta={'item': item})

            # again, yield the Request object


    def parse_3(self, response):
        item=response.meta['item']
        item['Website'] = response.xpath('.//[@id="mn-memberinfo-block-website"]/a/@href').extract()
        # OK, finally assume you're done, just return the item object
        return item
```

Comment: There are number of errors in your code, your **meta{...}** needs to be **meta={...}**, you're trying to **scrapy.Request()** with a list from **.extract()** etc. Do you know the basic of **scrapy** or it's just typo, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: from your **parse_page2** to other parse functions, you are yielding **item** whereas you should **yield** the **scrapy.Request**!

Comment: Yes, I am quite new to scrapy and have been looking at sample codes to figure it out. I made the changes to the psuedo code and have added another set of codes that I am actively working on.

Comment: not being rude but if you're new to **scrapy**, I recommend you learn by starting a smaller project. Learn each module/function **scrapy** brings you and make yourself understand how things work together, before putting many elements into 1 project which currently brings you a lot of headaches. But in general, for just a glance you're still making quite a few mistakes which definitely will raise errors. Perhaps could you tell me what exactly do you want to achieve and what data you're after? I may put together a working sample for your guidance

Comment: Those xpath I included in the codes are valid ones in the given site for 
http://cm.pschamber.com/list/
For this site, there are a list of industries or topics which provides about 20 more links. Within each of these 20 links, there are a couple of listing of companies that I want to grab specific data from. Here's a link of what I would like to do with scrapy http://www.screencast.com/t/XfUn9Gny7lox           You'll know what I mean. I probably need major help... if you are willing, my email is schanjr@gmail.com

Comment: OK but I will not do a full solution to you, but rather giving you a brief sample how to work these out together.

Comment: That is fine by me. Here are the points I need to clearly know in order to get these functions to work. I realize my codes are bulky and very intimidating, I am sorry about that. So here are the questions I have. How do I pass a nested href link to another function and use xpath on it? Since I need meta data from different levels of nested nested links, how do I retain it? For the example I gave you, here is the hiearchy:      Link 1 - Grab Industry ---> Link 2, ignore and get the link ---> link 3 Grab other information but needs to know which industry it belongs in.

Comment: HAPPY NEW YEARS AND DON'T WORK TOO HARD ON ANSWERING MY QUESTIONS! :D

Comment: Happy new year too! I've provided an answer already with all comments I think you need to know, rather than typing in this comment box. It doesn't take much of my time so don't worry lol. Hope this helps

Comment: You can access from response.meta['item'] as it's possesed item['industry'] all along. even in link2 --> link3, as long as you pass the `meta={'item':item}` and within another callback you do `item=response.meta['item']`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes you've made in your code therefore it's not running as you expected. Please see my below brief sample how to get the **items** you need and passing the **meta** to other callbacks. I am not copying your xpath as I just grab the most straight forward one from the site, you can apply your own.

I will try to comment as clear as possible to let you know where you did wrong.

```
class PschamberSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pschamber"
    # start from this, since your domain is a sub-domain on its own,
    # you need to change to this without http://
    allowed_domains = ["cm.pschamber.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://cm.pschamber.com/list/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = PschamberItem()
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="mn-ql"]//a'):
            # xpath and xpath().extract() will return a list
            # extract()[0] will return the first element in the list
            item['industry'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()[0]

            # another mistake you made here
            # you're trying to call scrapy.Request(LIST of hrefs) which will fail
            # scrapy.Request only takes a url string, not list
            # another big mistake is you're trying to yield the item,
            # whereas you should yield the Request object
            yield scrapy.Request(
                sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0],
                callback=self.parse_2,
                meta={'item': item}
            )
    # another mistake, your callback function DOESNT take item as argument
    def parse_2(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="mn-title"]//a'):
            # you can access your response meta like this
            item = response.meta['item']
            item['company'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            # again, yield the Request object
            yield scrapy.Request(
                sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0],
                callback=self.parse_3,
                meta={'item': item}
            )

    def parse_3(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['website'] = response.xpath('//a[@class="mn-print-url"]/text()').extract()
        # OK, finally assume you're done, just return the item object
        return item
```

Hope this is self-explanatory and you get to understand the basic of **scrapy**, you should **READ** thoroughly the doc from [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/), and sooner you will learn another method to set rules to follow links with certain patterns... well of course once you get the basic right you will understand them.

Although everyone's journey differs, I strongly recommend you keep reading and practice until you're confident in what you're doing before crawling actual website. Also, there are rules to protect web contents which can be scraped, and copyright about the content you scrape.

Keep this in mind or you may find yourself in big trouble in future. Anyway, good luck and I hope this answer helps you resolve the problem!

Comment: Hi Anzel, appreciate that you are taking the time to answer this. I have updated the code and attached it in my initial comment with your suggestions. However, during runtime I experienced error that said "in parse_3 item=response.meta['item'],,,exceptions.KeyError: 'item'. In parse_2, the key goes in fine, but it seems to be lost in parse_3. I tested this piece of code using "scrapy parse --spider=pschamber -c parse_3 -d 3 "http://cm.pschamber.com/list/".

Comment: @StanleyChan, glad it helps, if you've got an exception raised for **KeyError**, which means you haven't got the **Company** item return from the xpath... then technically you need to review the xpath or just simply change from **extract()[0]** to **extract()**